# On OS X, difference between drag & drop install vs copying to /Applications

Tags: xcode, macos, installation

I'm trying to automate the install of Xcode on an OS X machine. I've come across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649874/how-do-i-automate-the-installation-of-xcode) that got me most of the way.

The script given in the second answer gets the appropriate dmg mounted, and then uses `installer` to install the `pkg`. Except these days (e.g. version 7.3.1) Xcode is given as an app bundle inside the dmg, so there is no `pkg` to install. So I tried to simply copy it to `/Applications` via

```
cp -Rf /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app /Applications/
```

The resulting Xcode in my `/Applications` folder is 9.1 GB. But if I simply rename that bundle, manually open the dmg, and then drag & drop Xcode onto the Application shortcut, I end up with an Xcode that is 10.51 GB in size. Yet when I ask `opendiff` to compare the two, it tells me the contents are identical...

Does dragging & dropping from a dmg do something else under the hood, besides simply copying the app into `/Applications`? If so, is there a way to achieve the same via the command line?